# Tickle Invalidation Flag ViewOffsetHelper in the android design library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

What happens here? It looks odd to me, changing it results in weird behavior, getTranslation**X** but setTranslation**Y**? Is it a bug? Does this only work for Views that are not translated on X axis? Why are they not using `ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(view)`

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/ViewOffsetHelper.java#68

> ```
> private static void tickleInvalidationFlag(View view) {
>     final float x = ViewCompat.getTranslationX(view);
>     ViewCompat.setTranslationY(view, x + 1);
>     ViewCompat.setTranslationY(view, x);
> }
>
> private void updateOffsets() {
>     ViewCompat.offsetTopAndBottom(mView, mOffsetTop - (mView.getTop() - mLayoutTop));
>     ViewCompat.offsetLeftAndRight(mView, mOffsetLeft - (mView.getLeft() - mLayoutLeft));
>     // Manually invalidate the view and parent to make sure we get drawn pre-M
>     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
>         tickleInvalidationFlag(mView);
>         final ViewParent vp = mView.getParent();
>         if (vp instanceof View) {
>             tickleInvalidationFlag((View) vp);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Looks suspicious...  Are you getting some buggy behavior that you think is due to this code?

Comment: Yes, if I change "getTranslationX" to Y then my Views start to be wrong offsetted, in a way that doesn't make sense to me. If I comment it out and use `ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(view)` this happens, too.

Comment: It's probably a hack to invalidate the view in a way that works on all pre-M versions.  It looks weird that they get X and set Y; if I wrote code like that I would certainly put in a comment to explain why that's correct.  Perhaps once the views are invalidated they get the correct value from someplace else.  My intended question was:  Are you getting buggy behavior if you *don't* change it?  If not, I wouldn't worry about it.  Can't post a bug if it's not broken.  You could post that code to the Android Google group and ask why it works.